# VB.NET Event handler code inside the custom class runs first before the object itself event handler code

Tags: vb.net, class, events, triggers

I've created my own class c_DataGridView inherited from DataGridView. Now in this class I've implemented the event *CellEndEdit*.

Now I created an instance of this class/control  on my form named *myGrid1* and then I also implemented the same event of the grid here on my form.

Now when I run the form and edit a cell on the Grid the event trigger sequence is that: first my class c_DataGridView's *CellEndEdit* event triggers and then the object's event implemented on the form triggers.

Is there any possibility that I could manage to trigger the  event of c_DataGridView's object first and then the class's event itself.

I hope that I have cleared myself.

Comment: Seems to be some confusion with event and eventhandler in your question. If I get what you are saying, you might have been better with a BeforeCellEndEdit to use on the form. The problem with what you want to do is you are potentially making your component dependant on the form, which is bass ackwards

Comment: I have incorporated arrays inside my custom class and when the event CellEndEdit triggers it updates the array value from the cell. it's fine. But when I try to manipulate and update value of a cell say of a coulmn named "Amount" based on the other cell under the column "Percentage" this I have to do on the form. What I want now is that this calculation should be worked out first (event handler on the form) and then the event handler of the class should trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which event handlers are fired is unpredictable.  There's a standard pattern to deal with this, a .NET class always has a protected method with the same name as the event, prefixed with "On".

So in your derived class, override the OnCellEndEdit() method instead of subscribing the event.  You now have complete control over the way the event is getting handled and fired.  You can call base.OnCellEndEdit() first, then write your custom code.  Or you can call it last, first writing your custom code.  Or you can not call it, preventing the CellEndEdit event from getting fired at all.  Clearly you now have complete control over the order, the Right Way depends on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Excellent. It did the job exactly as I was looking for. (I also shifted my code under the method OnCellValueChanged instead of OnCellEndEdit). Also please let me know that where can I find this explaination in MSDN documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments I'd have gone a different way.

A class that matches a row.
A class that matches a list of Rows, witha BindingList Property.
Then I'd have bound that to the grid.
Then when Percentage was changed in the row class, update the Amount property. which would fire a property changed event, which would cause the grid to update.

So baically try and get all your data logic ina couple of classes, instead on inside event handlers in the presentation layer.